# how to avoid losing the automatically generated initializer-list constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

*I like the new automatically generated brace-enclosed initializers!*

Is there any way I can avoid losing them if I start to declare my own constructors?

**Code**

```
#include <string>

struct Foo
{
    int          i;
    std::string  s;

    // Foo() { }  // I lose my brace-enclosed initializers if I uncomment this line
};

int
main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Foo f{ 1, "bar" };  // having the option to do this is good

    return 0;
}
```

**ANSWER**

In light of [juanchopanza's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13980239/975129), it looks like I must satisfy the lengthy rules for [aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special).  But I still need a solution that I can apply to 50+ ORM classes (most with 5-15 fields each) that doesn't require a ton of boiler-plate code, or if there is boiler-plate code, at least it should be easy to edit/maintain.

The closest I could get was this solution using composition.  I wonder if there is something better/simpler...

```
#include <string>

// this class must satisfy the rules for aggregates
struct Foo_
{
    int          i;
    std::string  s;
};

// this class can be anything...
struct Foo
{
    Foo_         m_f;
    Foo( Foo_ const& f ) : m_f( f ) { }
};

int
main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Foo  f( { 1, "bar" } );   // ugly, but works

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not new and there is no constructor, nor initializer lists involved. Aggregate initialization has existed since ever.

Comment: @ildjam ty for your comment - is there any way I can generate one more automatically (maybe using c++11 functionality)?  I have like 50 database struct-related ORM classes - it's going to be painful hand-coding each one with 5-10 fields each, especially when the compiler knows how to do it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot avoid losing the automatic aggregate initialization because your class is no longer an aggregate. But you can add a constructor taking two parameters, and benefit from aggregate initialization for non-aggregates:

```
struct Foo
{
    int          i;
    std::string  s;
    Foo(int i, const std::string& s) : i(i), s(s) {}
    Foo() = default; // idiomatic C++11
};
```

Comment: that `default` is interesting - could I do this?  `Foo( int i, const std::string&s ) = default;`?  or something even shorter?  Looks like the compiler doesn't like it...

Comment: @kfmfe04 No, you can't do that. It only works for the "special" functions (copy and assignment operators, destructor, default constructor).

Comment: what's bugging me is simply because I add a constructor, I now have to hand-code what the compiler knows how to generate!  ARGH!

Comment: @kfmfe04 the logic of this particular corner of the language is that, once you define one constructor, the compiler can no longer safely know how to provide the others.

Comment: I could tell the compiler by adding the `default` like you mentioned - but for some reason, that is not allowed...  ...hmm...  maybe I can try containment or some other pattern